# Returning keywords from parsed webpage

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I`m using "ImportHtml" coupled with a Find function to parse a webpage, I would like to return one of 3 keywords IF it is found on the webpage.

This is what I`m using (in google Spreadsheet)

```
=If(FIND("Limited",INDEX(ImportHtml("http://www.fakeurl.com";"table";2),1,4))>0,"LIMITED",0)
```

but I don`t know how to scale it up to 3 keywords instead of just this single one knowing that we can only ever find one of those keywords (for example not 2 out or 3).

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=If(OR(FIND("Limited",INDEX(ImportHtml("http://www.fakeurl.com";"table";2),1,4))>0,FIND("keyword2",INDEX(ImportHtml("http://www.fakeurl.com";"table";2),1,4))>0,FIND("keyword3",INDEX(ImportHtml("http://www.fakeurl.com";"table";2),1,4))>0),"LIMITED",0)
```

If it finds any of those three words it put "LIMITED" in the cell.

If you want to display which keyword it found use this:

```
=IF(not(isna(FIND("Limited",INDEX(ImportHtml("http://www.fakeurl.com";"table";2),1,4)))),"limited",IF(not(isna(FIND("keyword2",INDEX(ImportHtml("http://www.fakeurl.com";"table";2),1,4)))),"keyword2",IF(not(isna(FIND("keyword3",INDEX(ImportHtml("http://www.fakeurl.com";"table";2),1,4)))),"keyword3",0)))
```

Comment: nice, it's nearly working, would you have a clue on how to return which keyword was found instead of retuning Limited all the time ?

Comment: ah, it's nearly doing it, but I didn`t cater for the fact that FIND is returning an error if it doesn't find the keyword, do you think I should try to wrap the "FIND" with some form of error checking if it doesn`t find the keyword ? thanks again for your help !

Comment: It's hard to test without your data, but the second one should work better now.